# gradle build Javadoc task fails with 'unknown tag: attr'

Tags: android, gradle, javadoc

I am attempting to build the [android-autofittextview](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) project from the command line using gradle. However, it fails every time with the following error:

```
/Users/me/android-autofittextview/library/src/main/java/me/grantland/widget/AutofitHelper.java:384: error: unknown tag: attr
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#TextView_textSize
```

This error is repeated a dozen times in various files.

This happens during the `:library:androidJavadocs`

I tried turning it off using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809868/android-studio-how-to-remove-or-disable-javadoc-generation-from-project-build), but then I get an 'unknown tasks' exception when I attempt to us this as a library project later on.

How can I get javadocs to build correctly with Gradle when the @attr flag is being used?

Answer (score 17):

A javadoc tool has an argument to specify **custom tags**. That parameter is *-tag*.

To pass that argument from gradle build file to javadoc tool add a configuration to your build.gradle as follows:

```
javadoc {
    options.tags = [ "attr" ] 
}
```

Custom tags can be specified as single argument with
`<name>:<placement>:<head>`:

```
javadoc {
    options.tags = [ "attr:a:head" ] 
}
```

Comment: Of course you can add more custom tags in that array.

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while to achieve this with Kotlin DSL but finally this works for me using Gradle 7.x:

```
tasks.withType<Javadoc> {
  (options as StandardJavadocDocletOptions).tags("attr:a:head")
}
```